# JS Scroll window while mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, custom-scrolling

I would like to scroll up or down the window while the mouse is over a specific element.

What I have so far basically works but it's not "smooth". It starts and stops on and on, not looking nice. Do you have any idea how to make a more constant smooth scrolling?

This is my code:

```
doScroll = 0;
$(".helperDown").mouseenter(function() {
    scrollHandler = setInterval( function() {
        console.log('scrolling down...');
        if(doScroll == 0) {
            doScroll = 1;
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: fromTop+50}, 200, 'linear', function() {
                doScroll = 0;
            });
        }
    }, 200);
});

$(".helperDown").mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(scrollHandler);
});
```

`.helperDown` is the area where the mouse has to be in to start scrolling. `fromTop` is always recalculated after a scroll event.

Comment: A first fix would be to re-start the animation directly from inside the animation callback , and removing the outer `Interval`

Answer (score 0):

You can not start a series of animation and expect a smooth scrolling. What you need is to start one animation only by pre-calculating the distance this animation will cover. Also, jQuery has a nice wrapper for mouseenter and mouseleave -combined. It's the hover() function with two functions as its parameter. The following code block will solve your issue. 
Also, this plnkr has both the up and down scroll feature:
https://plnkr.co/edit/WoneJ8?p=preview

```
$(function () {
    // change this value as per your need
    var distancePerSec = 1000;

    $(".helperDown").hover(function () {

        var h = $("body").height();
        var targetScrollTop = h - $(window).height();
        var distanceToTravel = targetScrollTop - $(window).scrollTop();
        var animationDuration = (distanceToTravel / distancePerSec) * 1000;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: targetScrollTop
        }, animationDuration, 'linear');

    }, function () {

        // stop the animation
        $("html, body").stop();

    });
})
```